# Looking for an optimum multithread message queue

Tags: multithreading, message-queue, messaging

I want to run several threads inside a process. I'm looking for the most efficient way of being able to pass messages between the threads.

Each thread would have a shared memory input message buffer. Other threads would write the appropriate buffer.

Messages would have priority. I want to manage this process myself.

Without getting into expensive locking or synchronizing, what's the best way to do this? Or is there already a well proven library available for this? (Delphi, C, or C# is fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to get right without repeating a lot of mistakes other people already made for you :)

Take a look at [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) - the library has several well-designed queue templates (and other collections) that you can test and see which suits your purpose best.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to work with multiple threads, it is hard to avoid synchronisation.  Fortunately it is not very hard.

For a single process, a Critical Section is frequently the best choice.  It is fast and easy to use. For simplicity, I normally wrap it in a class to handle initialisation and cleanup.

```
#include <Windows.h>

class CTkCritSec
{
public:
    CTkCritSec(void)
    {
        ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_critSec);
    }
    ~CTkCritSec(void)
    {
        ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_critSec);
    }
    void Lock()
    {
        ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_critSec);
    }
    void Unlock()
    {
        ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critSec);
    }

private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_critSec;
};
```

You can make it even simpler using an "autolock" class you lock/unlock it.

```
class CTkAutoLock
{
public:
    CTkAutoLock(CTkCritSec &lock)
    : m_lock(lock)
    {
        m_lock.Lock();
    }
    virtual ~CTkAutoLock()
    {
        m_lock.Unlock();
    }
private:
    CTkCritSec &m_lock;
};
```

Anywhere you want to lock something, instantiate an autolock.  When the function finishes, it will unlock.  Also, if there is an exception, it will automatically unlock (giving exception safety).

Now you can make a simple message queue out of an std priority queue

```
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct CMsg
{
    CMsg(const std::string &s, int n=1)
    : sText(s), nPriority(n) 
    {
    }
    int         nPriority;
    std::string sText;

    struct Compare : public std::binary_function<bool, const CMsg *, const CMsg *>
    {
        bool operator () (const CMsg *p0, const CMsg *p1)
        { 
            return p0->nPriority < p1->nPriority; 
        }
    };
};

class CMsgQueue : 
         private std::priority_queue<CMsg *, std::deque<CMsg *>, CMsg::Compare >
{
public:
    void Push(CMsg *pJob)
    {
        CTkAutoLock lk(m_critSec);
        push(pJob);
    }
    CMsg *Pop()
    {
        CTkAutoLock lk(m_critSec);

        CMsg *pJob(NULL);
        if (!Empty())
        {
            pJob = top();
            pop();
        }
        return pJob;
    }
    bool Empty()
    {
        CTkAutoLock lk(m_critSec);

        return empty();
    }

private:
    CTkCritSec m_critSec;
};
```

The content of CMsg can be anything you like.  Note that the CMsgQue inherits *privately* from std::priority_queue.  That prevents raw access to the queue without going through our (synchronised) methods.

Assign a queue like this to each thread and you are on your way.

**Disclaimer** The code here was slapped together quickly to illustrate a point.  It probably has errors and needs review and testing before being used in production.

Comment: Thanks Michael!

I saw a solution using ASM that negates the needs for any locks! I don't think that's possible in .Net.

Comment: @IanC  I don't see how you can do it without locks.  I'd guess that the ASM code is doing the locks itself.  If two threads try to access a queue simultaneously, without locks, bad things happen.  :-(  You can do your own locking, using the Interlocked*() functions, but generally that is no easier than just using a critical section.

Comment: I noticed that on my machine, I can lock & unlock 2 million times a second. But using atomic ASM functions, I can get perform over 20 million locks / unlocks a second (using cmpxchg). So there must be a significant difference between the two methods.

Comment: @IanC -- It depends on how fast the rest of the transaction is.  If locking is 10% of the transaction time and you reduce it to 0.01%, that may be pretty useful.  If it is 0.001% and you reduce it to 0.00001%, nobody cares.  
ASM will mostly be faster, but it can add heaps to the complexity, so you have to weigh up the cost/benefit.  
The C++ equicalent of cmpxchg is probably ::InterlockedExchange().  You might be able to do the same thing in C++.

Comment: This is true. I was comparing a simple Lock, Unlock, with no other functionality except for the timing loop, to the ASM equivalent.
I can only deduce that the .Net framework or Delphi (I timed both) is doing a lot more that the simple ASM CMPXCHG function. So I finally dug into the Delphi source (which, oddly, is half the speed on .Net). There are flags and API calls and other inefficient overheads there.

Thanks for helping me figure this out :)